# Can we have two routes with dynamic names in angular 5 website?

Tags: routes, angular5

The routes are as follows:

```
{
  path: ":referralCode",
  component: HomeComponent
},
{
  path: ':slug', 
  component: PagesComponent
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, As long as you can define distinct patterns for each you should be able to use a UrlMatcher. See https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher.

Example:

```
export function slugMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
    return url[0].path.startsWith('slug') ? ({consumed: url}) : null; // define a pattern for a slug??
}

export function referralMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
    return url[0].path.startsWith('ref') ? ({consumed: url}) : null; // define a pattern for a referal??
}

export const routes = [
    {
        matcher: slugMatcher,
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        matcher: referralMatcher, 
        component: PagesComponent
    }
];
```

Comment: Can you give an example? Thanks.

Comment: Done - you just need to decide on the pattern logic

Comment: can I make api calls inside this:                                                    
export function slugMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
    return url[0].startsWith('slug'); // define a pattern for a slug??
}

Comment: Not sure, but I wouldn't recommend it any case... I assume you want to verify whether a slug/referralCode exists before routing to it? Angular's various Guards are designed for that. https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: In this case, whichever route pattern matching happens first it checks that and stops there. What to do if I want to continue checking the next route if the first doesn't match?

Comment: Please retry with the updated code above - I've tested this and it works for me

Comment: Can you give an example using guards? {
        path: ':referralCode',
        component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [ReferralService]
    },
    {
        path: ':slug', 
        component: PagesComponent, resolve: { pageDetail: 'PageService'}
    }

Comment: What do you want to achieve with a guard, what have you tried and what is not working for you? If my answer solves this question perhaps you could mark it as correct. If you have trouble using guards I think this would be a separate question.